# NodeJS: Em um método do controller, como executar duas funções de models diferentes?

Tags: mysql, node.js

Eu preciso renderizar uma página com os dados de um Autor e a listagem das suas Notícias.

Nesse caso, estou considerando duas tabelas: autores e noticias e seus respectivos models.

Banco de dados: MySQL;

Relacionamento: 1 autor, n notícias.

---

**Tabelas**:

**autores**

id  nome  email

**noticias**

id  autor_id  titulo  texto

---

**Model Autor**

```
Autor.prototype.getAutor = function(id, callback){
    let result = this._connection.query(`select * from autores where id = ?`, id, callback);
    return result;
}
```

---

**Model Noticia**

```
Noticia.prototype.getNoticiasByAutor = function(autor_id, callback){
    let result = this._connection.query(`select * from noticias where autor_id = ?`, autor_id, callback);
    return result;
}
```

---

No controller, eu preciso de um método showAutorNoticias que deveria fazer algo como exemplificado abaixo, porém, desta forma não funciona.

***Qual é a forma de obter os dados do cliente e a lista das suas noticias no mesmo método do controller?***

---

**Controller Autor**

```
// Desejado algo parecido com isto:
 
module.exports.showAutorNoticias = function(application, req, res) {
    let id = req.params.id; // id do autor
    let connection = application.config.dbConnection;
    let Autor = new application.app.models.Autor(connection);
    let Noticia = new application.app.models.Noticia(connection);
 
    // 1 - Obter os dados do Autor (Apenas um exemplo da intenção).
    let autorData = Autor.getAutor(id, function(error, result) {
        return result;           
    });
 
    // 2 - Obter as noticias do autor (Apenas um exemplo da intenção).
    let noticias = Noticia.getNoticiasByAutor(autorData[0].id, function(error, result) {
        return result;
    });
 
    // 3 - Armazenar os dados do autor e suas noticias em um objeto;
    let autorNoticias = {
        id: autorData[0].id.toString(),
        name: autorData[0].nome,
        noticias: {
            noticias: noticias
        }
    }
   
    // 4 - Passar esse objeto para a view.
    res.render('admin/autor-noticias', { autorNoticias: autorNoticias });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de resolver é utilizando um [INNER JOIN](https://www.sqlshack.com/a-step-by-step-walkthrough-of-sql-inner-join/).

Segue um exemplo de como seria uma query para resolver este problema:

```
module.exports.showAutorNoticias = function(application, req, res) {
let id = req.params.id; // id do autor
let connection = application.config.dbConnection;
const sql = 'SELECT n.* FROM noticias n INNER JOIN autores a ON n.autor_id = a.id WHERE a.id = ?'

connection.query(sql, [id], (err, autorData, fields) => {
    if (err) {
        //renderizar página avisando que houve um erro.
    }
    console.log(autorData)
    if (autorData.length === 0) {
        //renderizar página sem artigos.
         res.render('admin/autor-noticias', { autorNoticias: [] });
    }
     // aqui estou apenas supondo mas talvez seja necessário adaptar o código
     // 3 - Armazenar os dados do autor e suas noticias em um objeto;
    let autorNoticias = {
        id: autorData[0].id.toString(),
        name: autorData[0].nome,
        noticias: {
            noticias: noticias
        }
    }
    // 4 - Passar esse objeto para a view.
    res.render('admin/autor-noticias', { autorNoticias: autorNoticias });
    })
}
```

Neste código implementei o fluxo que existe na documentação oficial da lib [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql).

Utilizei um `console.log` para mostrar os dados retornados pelo banco de dados, já que não conheço a estrutura interna de suas tabelas, mas com aquela informação dá pra montar a  `estrutura de dados` que deseja retornar ao usuário.

Em meu código verifico o tamanho do array `autorData.length`, faço isso pois mais abaixo no código você faz acesso direto ao índice zero do array.

Vale uma palavra de advertência em relação a utilização do seu parâmetro na clausura where não deve ser utilizada diretamente sem ser [sanitizada](https://medium.com/@abderrahman.hamila/what-sanitize-mean-and-why-sanitize-in-code-data-5c68c9f76164) antes, pois há o risco de [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), além de que se o usuário passar uma string ocorrerá um erro 500 em sua query.

Será necessário tratar quando o usuário passar um `id` de um `autor` inexistente na base (por exemplo: -1 ou) que no caso do inner join vai retornar 0 linhas ou null em sql.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas eu estou descartando o uso do INNER JOIN porque eu já conheço essa possibilidade.  A questão é: **Em um método do controller, como executar duas funções de models diferentes?**  Imagine outros dois casos:  1 - Os dados do Autor estão em um banco de dados X e as Noticias em um banco Y.  2 - Os dados do Autor estão em um bd e as Noticias são obtidas via Web Service.  Nesses dois casos é preciso executar duas funções no método showAutorNoticias para obter todos os dados.  Obs.: no PHP isso é feito tranquilamente.

Comment: Entendi, agora o seu requisito. Mas sim isso é possível. Você terá que fazer essa lógica de verificar em vários bancos utilizando o encadeamento de middlewares.